# Convert Html to mpdf gujarati text displaying wrong output

Tags: php, html, text, fonts, mpdf

I have some text issue in mpdf.

I have html code of student result in Gujarati language. I want to convert it to PDF. I used mpdf for that.

All thing is working properly but "Computer" word is coming wrong.

In HTML it is correct but after converting in pdf it is displaying wrong

In HTML(Correct) :  કોમ્પ્યુટર (Computer)

In PDF (incorrect) : કોમપ્યુટર (computer)

**Code**

```
<?php
    header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' ); 
    include("../../bootfile.php");
    include("../mpdf.php");
    mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<?php

    $mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8');

    $html = '
    Most of this text is in English, but has occasional words in  Vietnamese: Mô?t kha?o sa´t mo´i cho biê´t, or maybe even Arabic: 
    કોમ્પ્યુટર
    ';

    $mpdf->SetAutoFont();

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

    $mpdf->Output();

?>
```

What is the issue in it ? can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I myself a gujarati .. :) can you show us some code while you convert if possible.

Comment: which font you used ?

Comment: Make sure its not font support issue for the same.

Comment: I share my code